# Is the chameleon circuit attached to the chameleon arch?

Tags: doctor-who, tardis, chameleon-circuit

In The Family of Blood, the Doctor uses the chameleon arch to turn himself human. It is a cloak to hide his Timelord self from the family. The circuit is what makes the TARDIS the blue box. My question: are the chameleon circuit and chameleon arch connected, and if so, why did it turn him human if the circuit is broken? Please, a cannon answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the Sixth Doctor episode [Attack of the Cybermen](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Attack_of_the_Cybermen_%28TV_story%29) from 1985 showed the Doctor attempting to fix the chameleon circuit (causing the TARDIS to assume shapes other than a police box, though still malfunctioning since the shapes didn't serve the purpose of camouflage), and all he did was open a panel in the wall and mess with some electronics inside, as shown in image st--6t01.jpg from [this page](http://www.shillpages.com/dw/story-6.htm):

[image: Sixth Doctor]

The idea of the chameleon arch that could change a Time Lord's biology wasn't introduced until the 2007 Tenth Doctor episode [Human Nature](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Human_Nature_%28TV_story%29), and it was never suggested that it was connected to the chameleon circuit. Maybe the Time Lords just like the prefix "chameleon" for a device that disguises something's true nature.

Comment: Or Gallifreyan translation has no better word in English for what the machine does than "chameleon".  Like the time the Tenth doctor was teaching a physics class and he just kept saying the word "physics" over and over because his advanced knowledge of the topic couldn't be translated.  Haha